# How to take out Nothing out of inferred type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, types, f-bounded-polymorphism

The idea comes from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfaBeT0pRe0&t=526s, where they talk about implementing type safety through implementation of custom types.

And a possible trivial implementation is

```
trait Col[Self] { self: Self =>
}

trait Id extends Col[Id]
object IdCol extends Id

trait Val extends Col[Val]
object ValCol extends Val

trait Comment extends Col[Comment]
object CommentCol extends Comment

case class DataSet[Schema >: Nothing](df: DataFrame) {

  def validate[T1 <: Col[T1], T2 <: Col[T2]](
      col1: (Col[T1], String),
      col2: (Col[T2], String)
  ): Option[DataSet[Schema with T1 with T2]] =
    if (df.columns
          .map(e => e.toLowerCase)
          .filter(
            e =>
              e.toLowerCase() == col1._2.toLowerCase || e
                .toLowerCase() == col2._2.toLowerCase
          )
          .length >= 1)
      Some(DataSet[Schema with T1 with T2](df))
    else None
}

object SchemaTypes extends App {

  lazy val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(
      new SparkConf()
        .setAppName(
          getClass()
            .getName()
        )
    )
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val df = Seq(
    (1, "a", "first value"),
    (2, "b", "second value"),
    (3, "c", "third value")
  ).toDF("Id", "Val", "Comment")

  val myData =
    DataSet/*[Id with Val with Comment]*/(df)
      .validate(IdCol -> "Id", ValCol -> "Val")

  myData match {
    case None => throw new java.lang.Exception("Required columns missing")
    case _    =>
  }
}
```

The type for myData is `Option[DataSet[Nothing with T1 with T2]]`. It makes sense since the constructor is called w/o any type parameter, but in the video they show the type to be in line with `DataSet[T1 with T2]`.

Of course, changing the invocation by passing explicity type takes `Nothing` out, but it is redundant to specify the type parameter value since the types are already included in the arg list.

```
val myData =
  DataSet[Id with Val with Comment](df).validate(IdCol -> "Id", ValCol -> "Val")
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `Schema >: Nothing`? That seems like an unnecessary lower bound to me, since Nothing is the bottom type. I have a feeling `Schema` is inferred to `Nothing`, causing the return type of `validate` to also include `Nothing`

Comment: Also, where is `Schema` actually used, other than as a type argument to `DataSet` itself? There are no variables of type `Schema` anywhere, as far as I can see. I'd suggest removing it entirely, actually, or incorporating it in your constructor. You could also turn validate into a curried function accepting a dataframe and then the columns.

Comment: to date I have never used trait with big data, spark...

Comment: Schema is supposed to bring in the type of df, mix in the custom types and then return a type with schema mixed into col types. And the lower bound of nothing is unnecessary and redundant, I shall take it out

Comment: This means that this question is answered, right ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh removing lower bound `Nothing` doesn't change anything

Comment: "It makes sense since the constructor is called w/o any type parameter" In the code you show I don't see where; do you mean that `DataSet(df).validate(...)` gives `Option[DataSet[Nothing with T1 with T2]]` while `DataSet[Id with Val with Comment](df).validate(...)` works as expected?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I understood the question this way.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types `Id` and `Val` can be inferred because there are `IdCol` and `ValCol` inside `.validate`. But type `Comment` can't be inferred. So try

```
val myData =
  DataSet[Comment](df)
    .validate(IdCol -> "Id", ValCol -> "Val")

println(shapeless.test.showType(SchemaTypes.myData)) 
//Option[App.DataSet[App.Comment with App.Id with App.Val]]
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yj0HnpkyQfCreKq8ZV4D7A

Actually if you specify `DataSet[Id with Val with Comment](df)` the type **will be** `Option[DataSet[Id with Val with Comment with Id with Val]]`, which is **equal** (`=:=`) to `Option[DataSet[Id with Val with Comment]]`.

---

Ok, I watched the video till that time-code. I guess speakers tried to explain their idea (combining F-bounded polymorphism `T <: Col[T]` with intersection types `T with U`) and you shouldn't take their slides literally, there can be inaccuracies there.

Firstly they show slide

```
case class DataSet[Schema](df: DataFrame) {   
  def validate[T <: Col[T]](
    col: (Col[T], String)
  ): Option[DataSet[Schema with T]] = ??? 
}
```

and this code can be illustrated with

```
val myDF: DataFrame = ???
val myData = DataSet[VideoId](myDF).validate(Country -> "country_code")
myData : Option[DataSet[VideoId with Country]]
```

Then they show slide

```
val myData = DataSet(myDF).validate(
  VideoId -> "video_id",
  Country -> "country_code",
  ProfileId -> "profile_id",
  Score -> "score"
)

myData : DataSet[VideoId with Country with ProfileId with Score]
```

but this illustrating code doesn't correspond to the previous slide. You should define

```
// actually we don't use Schema here
case class DataSet[Schema](df: DataFrame) {
  def validate[T1 <: Col[T1], T2 <: Col[T2], T3 <: Col[T3], T4 <: Col[T4]](
    col1: (Col[T1], String),
    col2: (Col[T2], String),
    col3: (Col[T3], String),
    col4: (Col[T4], String),
  ): DataSet[T1 with T2 with T3 with T4] = ???
}
```

So take it as an idea, not literally.

You can have something similar with

```
case class DataSet[Schema](df: DataFrame) {
  def validate[T <: Col[T]](
    col: (Col[T], String)
  ): Option[DataSet[Schema with T]] = ???
}

val myDF: DataFrame = ???

val myData = DataSet[Any](myDF).validate(VideoId -> "video_id").flatMap(
  _.validate(Country -> "country_code")
).flatMap(
  _.validate(ProfileId -> "profile_id")
).flatMap(
  _.validate(Score -> "score")
)

myData: Option[DataSet[VideoId with Country with ProfileId with Score]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Taking the Schema out of the return type, as you have done in the code above, solves it as expected. The implementation I included in my original code, does take into account multiple type parameters but leaves Schema in the parameter argument of the return type.

Answer (score 2):

Dmytro Mitin's answer is good, but I wanted to provide some more information.

If you write something like `DataSet(df).validate(...)`, the type parameter of `DataSet(df)` is inferred first. Here it's `Nothing` because there's no information which would make it anything else. So the `Schema` is `Nothing`, and `Schema with T1 with T2` (which appears in the return type of `validate`) is `Nothing with Id with Val`.

Comment: Yes, and that is what I meant by 

"The type for myData is Option[DataSet[Nothing with T1 with T2]]. It makes sense since the constructor is called w/o any type parameter, but in the video they show the type to be in line with DataSet[T1 with T2]"

in my question